# How to identify the parent record related to a paused flow interview using a SOQL

Tags: apex, process-builder, visual-workflow

I need to cancel some of the actions scheduled by different process builders (executed on opportunity) but it is not easy to identify the related paused interview flow records....I dont know how can I do it.

I was thinking to use a SOQL in order to check if there is any way...it seems there are some objects like **FlowInterview**, **FlowInterviewShare** and **FlowRecordRelation**. The first two contains around 1.9K records but the last one returns 0 records, and it seems this one is the object that contains the relation between the paused flow interview and the record (opportunity)

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to set the `FlowRecordRelation` by setting the `{!$Flow.CurrentRecord}` system variable to a valid record ID in an Assignment element, I believe. That's why you see none. Are you only looking to cancel certain actions for certain records or by process builder? FlowInterview contains the `InterviewLabel` which has the name of the process builder.

Comment: but i need to delete only some of the FlowInterview related to the PB, not all of them...:(. Oh, or the future I can set that system variable, but for the current problem is not valid...

Comment: Unfortunately, you might not have any options in that case. All [examples](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_pause_cmp_record.htm&type=5) of this involve utilizing `FlowRecordRelation` which you have none of. You'll have to get creative and maybe can use `CreatedById` + PB Name on FlowInterview if you know who updated the record(s) you want to cancel. It's a lot, but it's something to help narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try to rerun those PB only for the involved opps changing some fields in order to see if automatically Salesforce removes the actions if the conditions are not valid anymore....

Comment: doc ref on setting [FlowRecordRelation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_pause_recordassoc.htm&type=5)